# PHP scandir() in Google Apps Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine

PHP scandir() in Google Apps Engine only returns '.php' files.

Eg:

```
My directory structure

-- index.php
-- Readme.txt
--CSS
-----abc.css
-----index.php
-----a.txt
```

But it only return '.php' files

## app.yaml

```
handlers:

- url: /(.+\.(css|js|xml|txt))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.+\.(css|js|xml|txt))

- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|jpeg))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|jpeg))

- url: /
  script: index.php

- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1

- url: /.*
  script: Error/404.php



function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            echo '<li>'.$ff;
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}

listFolderFiles('Main Dir');


Output:
1.CascadingStyleSheets
  1.index.php
```

In localhost its working fine. ie. returns all files and folders

How can i solve it?
Any solutions

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `.yaml` [static file handlers config doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#PHP_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers):

> For efficiency, App Engine stores and serves static files separately
>   from application files. Static files are not available in the
>   application's file system. If you have data files that need to be read
>   by the application code, the data files must be application files, and
>   must not be matched by a static file pattern.

Look below for the `application_readable` option:

> application_readable
>
> Optional. By default, files declared in static file handlers are
>   uploaded as static data and are only served to end users, they cannot
>   be read by an application. If this field is set to true, the files are
>   also uploaded as code data so your application can read them. Both
>   uploads are charged against your code and static data storage resource
>   quotas.

You may want to declare separate handlers for the static files you need in your app and use the `application_readable` option for them.

Here's an example (from one of my python apps):

```
- url: /buildin.py
  static_files: scripts/buildin.py
  upload: scripts/buildin.py
  application_readable: true
  secure: always
```

Comment: Thank you Dan for your detailed explanation

Comment: While deploying an error occured. "Unexpected attribute 'application_readable'"

Comment: do you have an example?